# Only one windows should be open at once in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am developing a WPF project in vb.net and have multiple windows in it. When user selects a menu item a new windows opens and the problem is when the user clicks on other menu item the current window should close by itself. 
How do i achieve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, I am very new to programming. I tried something like this Dim win3 As New Window3, win3.Show()

Comment: No problem. Put 'Dim win3 As New Window3' outside the method. Inside any method within the same class you can call 'win3.Show()' and 'win3.Close()'  Put public before Dim and it's available through other classes. Within the codebehind of any window you can call 'Me.Close()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this based upon your comment:

```
Class MainWindow 

  Public Win3 As Window3 = New Window3()

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Win3.Show()
    Me.Close()
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked. Well the issue is I have to explicitly close the window. I don't want to do this.  If I click on any other window the current open window should close itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

If the menu items share the same form then in the form create a subroutine, that you call instead of new, that checks if it is already shown/created and if not opens (as you already have). If it is open reload with the new information.

Otherwise before opening the new form go though the open forms (shown below from [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/591308-iterating-all-open-forms) website in C#):

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

foreach (Form frm in fc) {
         //iterate through
}
```

For each form check if it's name is equal to one of the menu items and if it is close it (after saving if required). Then after you exit the for loop you open the new menu item.