# How to check whether a window is open and close it in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application I want to close a particular window when I press a button in another window manually by coding, if it is opened. How to check whether a window is opened?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a window of your own program in which you are doing the checking? In some other program? Or a window of your office even? Please provide some details.

Comment: @Hans Kesting:- its a window of my program.

Comment: You mean that you have two windows in your application and when you click a button in one window, the other window should close. Is that your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817159/only-one-windows-should-be-open-at-once-in-wpf

Comment: @Cdeez :- yes sir, Thats my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really should be keeping track of this kind of thing yourself inside of your application…

But, since it sounds like you're not, you can lean on WPF to do it for you. It keeps track of all the open windows in your application, exposed through the [`Application.Current.Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) collection, so you can iterate through this collection looking for a match to windows of the type you're interested in.

For example:

```
foreach (var wnd in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (wnd is MyWindow)
    {
        // We found one!
        //
        // Close it or do something else interesting here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true)
{
    SearchAndDestroy("MyProgProc");
}


public SearchAndDestroy(string programname)
    {
     foreach (Process _proc in Process.GetProcesses()) {
                if (_proc.ProcessName.StartsWith(name))
                _proc.Kill();
            }
    }
```

I.E your program has two forms.
To call close form from another form.
Add button to formA:

```
private void button_click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
     FormB.ActiveForm.Disposed+= new EventHandler(CloseFormB)
}

private void CloseFormB(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
      FormB.ActiveForm.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: :- I want to close a particular window when i pressed a button in another window.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use linq like

```
var isWindowOpen = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().Any(x => (x == WINDOW));
```

WINDOW is window you want to check